# How to check if Jenkins build is waiting for input?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In Jenkins' Groovy, how can I detect that some other build is waiting for user input, as triggered by statements like `input message: 'Retry?' ok: 'Restart'`?

I checked the [Executor](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Executor.html) and [Build](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Build.html) API docus, but couldn't identify something that matches. `executor.isParking()` sounded promising, but returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Florian's answer is that if the input is waiting for a while, possibly across restarts of Jenkins, it might not be the last line in the log.

This is better:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.InputAction

def jobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(WorkflowJob.class)

jobs.each { job ->
  job.builds.each { build ->
    if (build.isBuilding() && build.actions.last() instanceof InputAction) {   
      println "$job.fullName #$build.number"
    }
  }
}
```

This one is looking specifically for `WorkflowJob` jobs but you could change the class to be `FreeStyleProject` or whatever other kind of thing you want to look for. But checking that the last action is input seems like a good way to know if it's waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid as it may be, this is the only hack I found so far:

```
def isWaitingForInput(WorkflowRun otherBuild) {
    def otherBuildsLog = otherBuild.getLog()
    return otherBuildsLog.lastIndexOf("0mAbort") >= otherBuildsLog .length() - 8
}
```

`0mAbort` is the piece of code that defines the *Abort* link that the user can click to abort the build while it is waiting for input.